# How to create multiple boxplots within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am new to Python and trying to plot multiple boxplots from a dataframe.

My dataframe is:

```
Date     A  B  C  D  E
01-Jan   1  3  6  6  1
01-Feb   2  4  7  4  2
01-Mar   3  5  8  2  9
```

I want to create 5 boxplots with where each boxplot represents an individual letter. How can I do it within a graph? Is there a systematic way to do when I have 100 columns so I don't have to type the column names for 100 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`DataFrame.boxplot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-Jan', '01-Feb', '01-Mar'],'A': [1,2,3],'B': [3,4,5],'C': [6,7,8],'D': [6,4,2],'E': [1,2,9],})
df = df.drop('Date',1)
df.boxplot(column=df.columns.tolist(), grid=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or  you can convert `df` to `dict` then plot `boxplots` like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-Jan', '01-Feb', '01-Mar'],'A': [1,2,3],
                   'B': [3,4,5],'C': [6,7,8],'D': [6,4,2],'E': [1,2,9],})

df = df.drop('Date',1)
dct = df.to_dict('list')

labels = dct.keys()
plt.boxplot(dct.values())
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Would you like to check out the edited question?

Answer (score 2):

Import the packages

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

To create the boxplot (requires pandas)

```
df.boxplot(column=list(df.columns))  # All columns
df.boxplot(column=list(df[['B', 'D']].columns))  # Selected columns
df.boxplot(column=list(df.drop(['B', 'D'], axis=1).columns))  # Drop columns
```

To show the plot (requires matplotlib)

```
plt.show()
```

Link for more info
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html

Comment: Would you like to check out the edited question?

Comment: @SssssssAaaaaaa I have adjusted the answer.